# Tomcat 7 logging still emits FINE and FINER logging, despite INFO being set everywhere

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to quell the ridiculous amount of logging Tomcat 7 emits out of the box.

For every single request, I get this amount of logging:

```
FINE: Security checking request POST /myurl
Aug 28, 2015 7:17:08 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Not subject to any constraint
Aug 28, 2015 7:17:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper allocate
FINER:   Returning non-STM instance
Aug 28, 2015 7:17:08 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
```

I have set my $CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties to this, to no avail.

(I basically took the default logging properties, and switched everything to info.  Also added `org.apache.catalina.level = INFO`)

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.
FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

org.apache.catalina.level = INFO


1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = INFO

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = INFO
```

Still I get FINE and FINER log messages.

edit:  more info.  I'm using tomcat inside of docker, [this particular image](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/b81ffe88c0bb6d760b6ee7d9c056469d59e68311/7-jre8/Dockerfile).

It is a very simple installation, no split base or anything:

```
ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME
```

**update**

I switched to the log4j logger as explained [here](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-logging) and [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j).  (one small error in the first link - tomcat-juli-adapter.jar goes in lib/, not bin/).  That solved my problem, but not with the out-of-the-box tomcat logger.  I'll leave the question up, though.

Comment: If you have a split `CATALINA_BASE` and `CATALINA_HOME`, do you have a `logging.properties` in `CATALINA_BASE` that is overriding the one in `CATALINA_HOME`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz No split base or anything.  simple install.

Comment: Did you check the root level level?

Comment: Could you indicate what the Tomcat startup parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you set the logging file property (***java.util.logging.config.file***) as specified in Tomcat docs? Excerpt below

...logging can be configured at the following layers:

- Globally. That is usually done in the
  ${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties file. The file is specified
  by the **java.util.logging.config.file** System property which is set by
  the startup scripts. If it is not readable or is not configured, the
  default is to use the ${java.home}/lib/logging.properties file in the
  JRE.
- In the web application. The file will be 
  WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties